# Installing bcrypt on ubuntu error message node api version

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bcrypt

I'm trying to install bcrypt using sudo npm install -g bcrypt but keep getting the following errors and i am not sure how to solve them. My npm version is 2.14.3 and node.js version is 3.3.1. I think the issue is my node api version is 1 and it requires version 3 but i don't know how to change that.

[image: error from trying to install bcrypt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a **very out-of-date version** of Node.js. Node 3 has been EOL for *many years* now. Upgrade to the latest LTS version for better support- currently the latest LTS is Node 18.